# Cloud HUGE data storage options?

Tags: video, video-streaming, large-files, data-storage

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to do video recording?

We have a camera that can record and then stream live video to a server. So this means we can have 1000's of cameras sending data 24X7 for recording. We will store data for over 7 / 14 / 30 days depending on the package.

- Per day if a camera is sending data to the server then it will store 1.5GB.
- So that means there is a traffic of 1.5GB / day / camera
- Total monthly 45GB / month / camera (Data + bandwidth for one camera)

Please let me know the most cost effective way to get this data stored?

Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: Each 15 minutes recording is saved as a single file, this gives users easy access to recorded files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun has a [lovely product optimized](http://www.sun.com/servers/networking/streamingsystem/) for this kind of thing, with a large Flash or RAM cache between big storage and the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used GlusterFS for (a bit diffrent type of) storage:

> GlusterFS is a clustered file-system
>   capable of scaling to several
>   peta-bytes. It aggregates various
>   storage bricks over Infiniband RDMA or
>   TCP/IP interconnect into one large
>   parallel network file system.

See here: http://www.gluster.org/docs/index.php/GlusterFS

It scales. Good luck (I think You will need it on this project).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "cloud" in your question subject line, and based on "package" details, sounds like you are not really facing merely a "storage" problem.  You also need to serve out the stored feeds to the user.

Will the stored video need to be streamed back (on demand) to multiple users or just the source user?  If the latter, you are looking at some sort of distributed forward cache layer, regardless of the storage back-end.

Comment: The video will only be served back to the user. Max there will only be 1GB of video download in a month or so.